# Can someone help me with curl for table?

Tags: curl, ios

I'm fairly new to the curl command, and since my country been hit with serious haze lately, I've been trying to get updated for the API since I have elderly at home and would like to keep them alert. The site I've been getting index is from http://apims.doe.gov.my/public_v2/api_table.html

However, curl the site didn't give me any value on the table. I'm trying to extract the latest hourly data for a city (for example Rompin).

I'm using a jailbroken iOS if that's relevant. Could someone help me with this? Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for the table appears to be coming from `http://apims.doe.gov.my/data/public/CAQM/last24hours.json`. I'm not sure what you're using on iOS that's allowing you run `curl`, but if it includes a package manager or similar you can consider installing [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON.

Comment: Thank you! I did solved it using `jq` :)